# create conditional priority in add_action

Tags: wordpress, add-action

For a plugin, i am trying to set a different priorirty when adding an element to de admin menu bar. For administrators, it is another position then for all other user roles.
I tried to define the priority as a variable in another function, return the correct priority based on the user role, and then insert this variable in the add_action statement. However, this keeps throwing errors. I assume because the add_action is earlier executed then the check for user roles.

So far I have the following:

```
set_priority() {
    $priority = 51;
    if (current_user_can('manage_options')){
    $priority = 21;
    }
    return $priority;
    }
add_action('init','set_priority');
```

And next:

```
function add_context_tab($wp_admin_bar) {

if(current_user_can('manage_options')){
    $url = network_site_url(). 'wp-admin/network/admin.php?page=content-page';
}
else{
    $url = network_site_url(). 'wp-admin/admin.php?page=content-page';
}

global $wp_admin_bar;

$wp_admin_bar->add_node( array(
    'id'    => 'content-page',
    'title' => '<span class="ab-icon dashicons dashicons-welcome-add-page"></span>' . __( 'Add content' ),
    'href'  => $url,
) );
}
$priority = set_priority();
add_action ('admin_bar_menu','add_context_tab',$priority);
```

I get an error: call to undefined function wp_get_user_roles
I tried to change the priority from function set_priority that didnt work.
I tried to include pluggable.php but get an error with undefined constant AUTH_COOKIE.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps putting the `add_action('admin_bar_menu','add_context_tab',$priority)` in the `set_priority()` function would work

```
set_priority() {
    $priority = 51;
    if (current_user_can('manage_options')){
        $priority = 21;
    } 
    add_action('admin_bar_menu','add_context_tab',$priority)
}
add_action('init','set_priority');
```

Comment: Doesnt work either, at least if i understand you correctly. I tried it by putting this code directly in the file and other option i tried was to include both functions in one function, ending with the add_action ('init' hook at the end. Both give errors.